# Laravel Passport (Client Credential Grant Type) Login not defined

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I came across this issue who is already well known with the community, but I still can't fix this problem. I tried everything but it's showing again the same exception:

```
Route [login] not defined.
```

What is already applied inside my code.

1. I've added already `CheckClientCredentials::class` inside my `$routeMiddleware` array.
2. Don't use `auth:api`.
3. Retrieving the 0auth2.0 with `Client Credentials Grant Type` token is successful.

- ../oauth/token (via Postman Authorization)

4. Get the exception only after retrieving the token and getting users (custom end-point).

- ../api/users (get)

Maybe I miss something important?

Comment: Show your login route. It probably doesn't have a name associated with it

Comment: I don’t need any Login route because I already use Client Credentials Grant Type. That’s the whole reason of my question.

Comment: Then something somewhere, most likely a view template, is trying to access `route('login')`. Find it and remove it if you don't need it

Comment: @aynber place your comment as answer, then I can mark it as an answer.